# Combine regex groups and search for matches/ search for multiple regex groups

Tags: java, regex

What I have now:

```
private static final String[] CD_LISTING = new String[] {
        "first", "second", "third", "furthermore", "finally",
        "to begin", "to conclude", "next"
};
private static final String[] CD_REINFORCEMENT = new String[] {
        "also", "furthermore", "moreover", "what is more",
        "in addition", "besides", "above all", "as well as",
        "as well", "in the same way"
};
private static final String LISTING =
        "(?i)\\b(" + String.join("|", Arrays.CD_LISTING) + ")\\b";
private static final String REINFORCEMENT =
        "(?i)\\b(" + String.join("|", Arrays.CD_REINFORCEMENT) + ")\\b";

private static int patternMatcher(String matcherGroup, Pattern pattern) {
    int occurrence = 0;
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Text.getTextToAnalyse());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(matcherGroup) != null) occurrence++;
    }
    return occurrence;
}
public static final Pattern CD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<LISTING>" + LISTING + ")|(?<REINFORCEMENT>" + REINFORCEMENT + ")")
```

I use `patternMatcher("LISTING", CD_PATTERN)` to search for occurence of `LISTING` and `patternMatcher("REINFORCEMENT", CD_PATTERN)` to search for occurence of "REINFOREMENT". However, as I have numerous groups, it would be stupupid to create another group. Is there a way to combine such groups without repeating the elements?

e.g. "furthermore" is a repeated element in the groups.

I would like to search for the total occurences. However, if I just add up `LISTING` and `REINFORCEMENT`, repeated words such as "furthermore" will be counted twice.

Is there a way to search for multiple groups at once or a way to combine these matcher groups? many thanks

Comment: You do know that `"furthermore"` will never be counted as `"REINFORCEMENT"`, right? So `patternMatcher("LISTING", CD_PATTERN) + patternMatcher("REINFORCEMENT", CD_PATTERN)` *is* the total occurences.

Comment: @Andreas why so? An explaination would certainly help thanks. I'm still a noob :(

Comment: Because when regex matches against an expression with `|`, it'll use the first one that matches. Since `"furthermore"` is matched in the `LISTING` block, it'll never match in the `REINFORCEMENT` block. Each `find()` will only match against one of the blocks, and then the search continues *after* that point in the input text.